# VBA Advanced filter unique values and copy to another sheet

Tags: vba, excel, filter, unique

I've tried a number of methods to filter a column for unique values (including blanks and blanks with a space inside). I want to filter these values and then paste them into column a in another sheet.

```
Sub filter_2()
    With Sheets("ICM flags")

        .Columns("a").AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=Sheets("Flag Update (2)").Range("a2"), Unique:=True

    End With
End Sub
```

The method above works for `.range("a2")` but if I try to use `.range("a1")` I get runtime error 1004 advanced filter method of class failed.

I get runtime error 1004 advanced filter method of class failed with the method below.

```
Sub unique_filter()

               Sheets("ICM flags").Columns("a").AdvancedFilter _
                     Action:=xlFilterCopy, _
                        copytorange:=Sheets("Flag Update (2)").Range("a1"), Unique:=True

End Sub
```

For both of the above methods and with the edits to Davesexcel answer:

```
Sub AdvFilter()
Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
Dim rng As Range, Frng As Range

Set sh = Sheets("ICM Flags")
Set Frng = sh.Range("A:A")
Set ws = Sheets("Flag Update (2)")
Set rng = ws.Range("A1")

'Frng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=rng, Unique:=True
Frng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, Unique:=True

End Sub
```

The method works for `FilterInPlace` but not `CopyToRange`

Comment: Sometimes (not always) this error happens if the range you are filtering is not selected. Try selecting the range before filtering. Selection *should not* be required, but I've seen it make the difference.

Comment: I believe you need to use variables if you want to copy advance filter to another sheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems the problem was being caused by trying to use `CopyToRange` to copy to another sheet. I have worked around this by first copying to the same sheet then copying these values to the sheet I want them on

```
Sub AdvFilter() 'filters flags copied from ICM to unique values and pastes  into Flag update sheet.

    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, Frng As Range, Prng As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Flag Update (2)")

    Set sh = Sheets("ICM Flags 1")'destination sheet
    Set Frng = sh.Range("A:A")'filter range
    Set rng = sh.Range("c1")'filter output range


    Frng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=rng, Unique:=True
    ws.Columns("a").Value = sh.Columns("c").Value 'Separate copying as the filter didn't like copying to another sheet

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3):

When I ran your code, it worked with no errors on my end.

This is the same code but using variables and might work better for you.

```
Sub AdvFilter()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, sh As Worksheet
    Dim rng As Range, Frng As Range

    Set ws = Sheets("Flag Update (2)")
    Set rng = ws.Range("A1")
    Set sh = Sheets("ICM flags")
    Set Frng = sh.Range("A:A")

    Frng.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=rng, Unique:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Looks like that will work well, should have thought of it myself really! I'll check it later on today and accept your answer if I have no problems. Cheers

Comment: Strangely, when I test this I get 1004 'missing or illegal field name'. I have run it with the locals window open and can't seem to see any problems - any ideas? Cheers

Comment: Lets see your code, I will try and duplicate the problem. You can add it to your original post.

Comment: Ah, that is a good idea but unfortunately in this case I have manually exported the a column of data from InfoWorks ICM and pasted it into .xlsm to use the filter code on. All of the code I have written comes after the filter step which I am currently bypassing manually to get my work done.

Comment: Then why not use code to copy the column to the other sheet then remove duplicates.

Answer (score 1):

Actually 
The destination needs to be made the active sheet, then you can get unique values from any other sheet or workbook

Answer (score 0):

Here what is used on my unique filter. It will copy from `sheet1` and paste in `sheet2`.

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()
    Dim UserRange As Range
    Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A:A").Clear
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")
    On Error Resume Next
    Set UserRange = Application.Range("A:A")
    On Error GoTo 0
    If UserRange Is Nothing Then
        Exit Sub
    End If     
    UserRange.AdvancedFilter _
        xlFilterCopy, CopyToRange:=Sheets("BOM").Range("A1"), Unique:=True
End Sub
```