# Create unique list from a column display the results in a drop down using the Ribbon bar display the filter on the worksheet

Tags: excel, vba, ribbon

I have 29,000 plus rows on a sheet called `DataCalcs`. In column `AG`  I have values like the following:

```
Altern 1
Altern 1
Altern 1
Altern 1
Altern 1
Altern 1
Base   2
Base   2
Base   2
Base   2
Base   2
```

and so on in column `AG`

I need code that will filter this data and display what is filtered from a custom Menu I have created on the Excel Ribbon.

I also need the data to be displayed on the `DataCalcs` worksheet when the menu on the drop down from the Ribbon Bar is selected based on the unique selections in column `AG`that are filtered.

I also have saved this data in a range called `DataCalcs` so please feel free to use that named range in the code.

Thanks for looking and reading!

Comment: So... what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

[image]

**These procedures do the work:**
`Sub AdvFilter` is actually just one line of code.
`Sub AdvFilterSort` includes the possibility to sort the result.

```
Option Explicit

'Sub AdvFilter and Sub AdvFilterSort
'based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32787227/vba-advanced-filter-unique-values-and-copy-to-another-sheet

Sub AdvFilter(InputRange As Range, OutputRange As Range)
    InputRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=OutputRange, Unique:=True
End Sub

Sub AdvFilterSort(InputRange As Range, OutputRange As Range, Optional sortHeader As Integer, Optional sortAscOrDesc As Integer)
    Dim sortRange As Range
    InputRange.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterCopy, copytorange:=OutputRange, Unique:=True
    If sortAscOrDesc = xlAscending Or sortAscOrDesc = xlDescending Then
        Set sortRange = OutputRange.CurrentRegion
        sortRange.Sort key1:=OutputRange, Order1:=sortAscOrDesc, Header:=sortHeader
    End If
End Sub
```

**This procedure calls AdvFilter/AdvFilterSort with your "DataCalcs" data:**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Call_AdvFilter()
    Dim agRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    'Create a new sheet for the results : "newSheet"

    If sheetExists("newSheet") Then
        'nothing to do
    Else
        'create sheet and name it "newSheet"
        Sheets.Add after:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)
        ActiveSheet.Name = "newSheet"
    End If
    lastRow = Worksheets("DataCalcs").Range("A1").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row
    Set agRange = Range("DataCalcs!AG1:AG" & lastRow)

    'Delete result columns
    Range("newsheet!A:H").Delete

    With Worksheets("newSheet")
        .Range("A1:H3").Font.Bold = True
        .Range("A1:H1").Font.Size = 14
        .Range("A3:H3").Font.Size = 12

        'using column ag data defined with lastrow
        .Range("A1").Value = "Column AG data (lastrow):"

        'result sorted:
        .Range("A3").Value = "sorted"
        Call AdvFilterSort(Range("DataCalcs!AG1:AG3340"), .Range("A5"), xlNo, xlAscending)

        'result not sorted:
        .Range("C3").Value = "not sorted"
        Call AdvFilter(Range("DataCalcs!AG1:AG3340"), .Range("C5"))


        'using predefined range named "DataCalcs"
        .Range("F1").Value = "defined Name ""DataCalcs"":"

        'result sorted:
        .Range("F3").Value = "sorted"
        Call AdvFilterSort(Range("DataCalcs"), .Range("F5"), xlNo, xlAscending)

        'result not sorted:
        .Range("H3").Value = "not sorted"
        Call AdvFilter(Range("DataCalcs"), .Range("H5"))

    End With
End Sub
```

**This is a nice sheetExists function used above:**

```
Function sheetExists(sheetToFind As String) As Boolean
    'copied from:
    'https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6040164/excel-vba-if-worksheetwsname-exists
    'by Dante is not a Geek
    'https://stackoverflow.com/users/571433/dante-is-not-a-geek
    Dim mySheet As Worksheet
    sheetExists = False
    For Each mySheet In Worksheets
        If sheetToFind = mySheet.Name Then
            sheetExists = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next mySheet
End Function
```